# Apache CXF 2.7.7 WebClient - Change the URI of the request in ClientRequestFilter

Tags: filter, jax-rs, cxf, interceptor

I need to redirect the client calls by modifying the URI.

I tried the following:

```
    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext clientRequestContext) {
        ...
        clientRequestContext.setURI(changedURI);
        Message m = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage();
        m.put(Message.REQUEST_URI, changedURI);
        m.put(Message.BASE_PATH, changedURI);
   }
```

None of this works, it still sends to the original URI. Any comments?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found a solution?

I also tried to change the BASE_PATH on the message exchange, but it is also ignored if the request is executed.

Comment: No, I did not. You can use the versions later than this. 2.7.19 works.